# Version control system for closed source project

Tags: c#, version-control

I'm looking for somekind of version control system where I can create a repository for my project, like SVN for example, but with the abillity to define which portion of the source some user will be able to see and commit changes. If possible, that the user can run a local copy of the project, but without seeing the complete source.

I have a closed-source project and I want to add more developers into it, but I do not want them to see some parts of the source right now, and I don't know which system is better for me.

I already searched for Git, Bitbucket, Assembla (currently using this one), SourceForge, and Google Code, but I think none of them has the feature I am looking for.

Comment: Depending on your code base, you could just create sub-repositories in Git.

Comment: Restructure your project to have the parts that you do not wish to give access to others separated from the others and use separate repositories for them but build them into libraries/components/whatever and distribute them to the other users.  Interfaces may also need to be separated from both.  Then you can use almost any VCS just restrict the access to the private parts.

Comment: What if they use .net reflector for instance in the portion of the source I dont want them to see, that I build a separate .dll file to contain it, they will see all my code there. Is there a way to protect? Maybe just packing the dlls would solve? I'm not discussing if the pack is crackable or not, thats not the point, just don't want to  give them so easy, you know. But I don't think they will try to decompile, just a precaution

Comment: hmm... I don't have any money to be honest, this is a hobby project, but can you elaborate more about these systems? And is there any free solution? The solution @SteveBarnes said seems fine to me, but I am worried about decompilation of my libraries.

Comment: Any code can be decompiled if enough effort is put into it a better trick is to embed some items in your code which are not easy to find and remove but allow you to prove that someone is using a copy without permission if it happens.

Comment: Why not use svn? You can put per-directory access permissions. Svn only does version control though, not the build automation that you seem to implicitly want as well so that you can distribute binaries for some components.

Answer (score 1):

A possible option is to use git submodules. You would need to structure the code as @Steve Barnes said so that what you want to hide can be in a separate submodule.

Git submodule documentation and guide can be found here:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 1):

[Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) has all basic access abilities.

- users, groups
- permissions which can be applied across repository tree for users/groups

[image]

The product

- is **free** up to 20 users and 20 workspaces
- has user interface superior to most of similar products  I have seen
- has plugins into many popular IDE's and integration with Windows Explorer
- is well-documented and supported even in free edition